# Factorizing $12x^3 - 8x^2 - 3x + 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, cubics

How should I factorize this cubic expression?

$$12x^3 - 8x^2 - 3x + 2$$

Comment: Do you know the rational roots theorem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We observe that $12:8=3:2$

So

$\begin{array} 
112x^3 - 8x^2 -3x + 2  \\
&=&4x^2(3x-2) - (3x-2) \\
&=&(3x-2)(4x^2 - 1)\\
&=&(3x-2)((2x)^2 - 1^2)\\
&=&(3x-2)(2x+1)(2x-1)  \\
\end{array}$